# TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to string implicity

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, int

I can't figure out why I get the error:  `TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to string implicity`

This is the relevant code for the class:

```
class Pig():

def __init__(self, name, age, weight, value):
    self.name = name
    self.age = age
    self.weight = weight
    self.value = value

def runAndGainValue(self, value):
    self.value += value  #This is where the error occur.

def __str__(self):
    a = self.name + " "
    a += str(self.value) + " "
    return a
```

And here's the part of the code for the main program:

```
elif work == "2":
    yourfarm.printAnimals()
    print ("blablablabla")
    for pig in p:
        pig.runAndGainValue(5)
    yourfarm.printAnimals()
```

And I can't figure out why I get this error. I've tried searching for it but I am new with programming so I have a lot of trouble with interpreting a totally different code but with the same problem. Very much grateful for your help ahead.

Comment: where does the error occur?

Comment: is self.name a string, or are you passing in a number when you create the Pig object?

Comment: Ops sry, I've edited the question and commented where the error occur.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean because I'm a superbeginner. But the self.name is decided in my class for the farm. with for i in self.animals: print(i.name,i.weight, and so on).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have set the `value` of your pig to a string, then when you call `pig.runAndGainValue(5)` you are trying to add an integer to a string:

```
def runAndGainValue(self, value):
    self.value += value
```

This raises an exception as Python strings are not implicitly converted to numbers, even when their value could be interpreted as a number:

```
>>> '10' + 5
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly
```

When creating the `Pig`, make sure `value` in an integer, always. Perhaps you need to explicitly convert in the initializer:

```
def __init__(self, name, age, weight, value):
    self.name = name
    self.age = int(age)
    self.weight = int(weight)
    self.value = int(value)
```

or just make sure your inputs are integers.

Comment: I see. That brings me a new problem, because of how I've decided the age, weight, and value in my main code. I wrote it like Pig("bla the pig", "age: 2", "weight: 50" if you understand what I mean.

Comment: @Bondenn: You cannot do that; let the attribute names themselves determine what the value means, don't store strings with added metadata like that.

Comment: @Bondenn: At least, parse out the value: `self.age = int(age.rsplit(':', 1)[-1])` would get *just* the part of the string after the last `:` and turn that into an integer.

Comment: Okey that's my bad for being a beginner! But how do I do it when I want the attributes to be decided? For example: If you buy a pig it should be presented with, Name: Pig, Age: 2, Weight: 50kg and so on?

Comment: @Bondenn: leave *that* to the printing code; take a look at [the string format syntax](http://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) to make that part easier.

Comment: Ok a lot of info at the same time, not sure if I understand it. But i'll try taking a look at the string format syntax in hope to get closer of solving the problem!

Comment: @Bondenn: The bottom line is: store the simplest type that can represent your values; an `int` is *much* easier to manipulate than a string containing a number.